# How to make attach socket.io event in custom prototype methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

How to make `$.tpt.prototype.socket.on("connect", function() {});` in the following class?

skeleton.js:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3003');
socket.on("connect", function () {
});


(function ($) {
  var uuid = {};  

  $.tpt = function (options) {
    this.boot();
  };

  $.tpt.prototype.boot = function(msg) {
    alert("page loaded");   
  };

  //attach that events of socket here how??

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3003');
socket.on("connect", function () {
});


(function ($) {
  var uuid = {};  

  $.tpt = function (options) {
    this.boot();
    this.socketOn('connect',function(){});

  };

  $.tpt.prototype.boot = function(msg) {
    alert("page loaded");   
  };

  $.tpt.prototype.socketOn = function(event,fn){
       socket.on(event,fn);
  };
})(jQuery);
```